# How to fix 'AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute ... ' error in python assert

Tags: json, python-3.x, assert

I'm setting up a request assertion with request module and python assert keyword but getting

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'documentation_url'

when I try to assert a string in json response. How do I assert something within the json response and when the condition is true, it should print out something?

```
import requests
import pprint

URL = 'https://github.com/timeline.json'

def get_github_json(URL):
    response = requests.get(URL).json()
    return response

assert get_github_json(URL).documentation_url == 'https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-public-events'
```

The json response looks like this:

```
{'documentation_url': 'https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-public-events',
 'message': 'Hello there, wayfaring stranger. If you’re reading this then you '
            'probably didn’t see our blog post a couple of years back '
            'announcing that this API would go away: http://git.io/17AROg Fear '
            'not, you should be able to get what you need from the shiny new '
            'Events API instead.'
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Hi because it's a dictionary then you would have to get the value with a key.

We know `response` is a dictionary, so in this case when you want the value from the `documentation_url`, we would need to do it like this:

```
    def get_github_json(url):
        response = requests.get(url).json()
        return response

    assert get_github_json(url)['documentation_url'] # <---- your are getting the value by giving the key
```

If you try and print out `response['documentation_url']` then you would get this result:
`https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-public-events`